# Documentum Workflow Dillemma

Tags: documentum

I am tring to figure out how to add workflow activities to a package in DFS, in other words how to add performers to the activity through DFS code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark (because I haven't touched DFS in years) but I bet you could add them via DQL.  Do the activities already exist and just aren't wired to the specific workflow, or are you creating new activities as well?

Comment: Nope not creating any activities through DFS. I have used processinfo and its related class libraries to get that done .